# How to do "is contained in" using ElasticSearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Let's say I have a sentence of text and want to find all documents where field X is found in that sentence.

**Example:**

"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" is my sentence.

I have 3 documents.  Each has a single field called keyword:

- 1, keyword = fox
- 2, keyword = dog
- 3, keyword = cat

I want to run a query that checks if keyword appears in the supplied value, so 1 and 2 would match, but 3 would not.

I've checked the documentation and thought I might be able to do it with "fuzzy_like_this" but it's returning me documents that don't even have the "keyword" field.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search it using a query parser with an appropriate analyzer, like:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_48, "keyword", analyzer);
Query query = parse.parse("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
int maxHits = 10; //Or however many you want
TopDocs topdocs = indexSearcher.search(query, maxHits);
```

The query above will search for each term present in the keyword field, so the query will look something like (the is a stop word, by default, and so will be eliminated):

```
keyword:quick keyword:brown keyword:fox keyword:over keyword:lazy keyword:dog
```

In elasticsearch, the equivalent is a [query string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "keyword",
        "query" : "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchos gracias.  That looks like exactly what I need.  It didn't seem obvious from the query_string description but putting it into practice it works perfectly.